# How to limit/clean my DLLs from Appdata\Local\assembly\tmp

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, temp

I have a VB.Net Word AddIn project, and at some customer's computers, I'm getting complaints of the `%LocalAppData%/assembly` filling up with my application's DLLs.

It's mostly the `tmp` subfolder, but also the `dl3`.

I just wonder if this is something that is caused by environment setup specifics at the customer's site, of if there's something I can do to resolve it in my code.

Whatever the cause, I hope to find a solution other than telling the customer to just `"Run disk-cleanup on the affected pc's"`.

[Here's a sample list](https://pastebin.com/zYpQ3y7K) of content in the `tmp` subfolder, some assembly names have been changed though, so as not to expose other software running at the client's pc.

*(Sorry about the pastebin thing, but it's >1400 lines, so it wouldn't fit here...)*

My assembly named `MyApplication.DLL` is grossly overrepresented. Like 5:1 or more. In this case it's about 1.7 GB of the folder's total of 2.45 GB. I have reports of this being over 5 GB in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This can't be managed in code.**

That's my conclusion so far.